# Version Numbers in a project with Qt

Tags: qt, preprocessor, version, build-process

Version numbers are needed all over a project; in installers, code, toolchains etc. I despise duplication. I want my version numbers to be stored in one central authoritative location.

I am working with C/C++ and using Qt on various platforms. In Qt, qmake projects specify version numbers like:

```
VERSION = 1.2.3
```

In code I use something like in a header like Version.h:

```
#define VERSION_MAJ 1
#define VERSION_MIN 2
#define VERSION_REV 3
#define VERSION_STRING \"VERSION_MAJ\" "." \"VERSION_MIN\" "." \"VERSION_REV\"
```

My installer toolchain has support for C preprocessing so I can use the same version specified in Version.h. However, I don't know how to get qmake to use the same version number. I thought I could preprocess the pro file, but that won't work as # characters mean a comment in pro files and the C preprocessor will fall over.

Anyone know of a good way to keep my version number centralised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to store your version numbers in a c header file, you can do so and then import them into the Qt project variables in the project file. Something like the below should work:

Version.h:

```
#define MY_MAJOR_VERSION 3
#define MY_MINOR_VERSION 1
```

.pro

```
HEADERS  += Version.h

VERSION_MAJOR = MY_MAJOR_VERSION
VERSION_MINOR = MY_MINOR_VERSION
```

The advantage of doing it this way round is that you can then use your authoritative header file if you need to compile other parts of the project away from Qt.

Comment: Good idea. But to get them together, it's going to require some tokenization magic.

Comment: This actually doesn't work -- `MY_X_VERSION` is not available in the .pro file, even if Version.h is added to HEADERS (`qmake` doesn't read header files and turn `#defines` into qmake variables.)

Answer (score 27):

I use something like this in my build system

```
#.pro file
#Application version
VERSION_MAJOR = 1
VERSION_MINOR = 0
VERSION_BUILD = 0

DEFINES += "VERSION_MAJOR=$$VERSION_MAJOR"\
       "VERSION_MINOR=$$VERSION_MINOR"\
       "VERSION_BUILD=$$VERSION_BUILD"

#Target version
VERSION = $${VERSION_MAJOR}.$${VERSION_MINOR}.$${VERSION_BUILD}
```

And after that you can use VERSION_MAJOR and others as normal macro in your application.

Comment: @oggmonster The same way as you use other macros in your application, for example `QString("%1.%2.%3").arg(VERSION_MAJOR).arg(VERSION_MINOR).arg(VERSION_BUILD);`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Now, is there any way to get this VERSION into the "info.plist" component of the .app file?

Comment: @MichK Thanks. How can i cause this version number to be in the compiled application bin/elf file (in linux) ?

Comment: using this method, when my project is already compiled and I increment the version, the change is not taken into account and I need to clean the whole project or remove the depending .o files to apply the change. Do someone has a elegant solution ?