# Get version of Qt app in code

Tags: qt, qmake

Is it possible to get in my code VERSION from .pro file of qt project?
I don't want to write twice version of my app: the first in .pro file and the second in code of my app.

Comment: pass it to cflags as -D

Comment: How? May you show how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this into your `.pro` file:

```
VERSION=0.1
DEFINES += APP_VERSION=$$VERSION
```

Then you can use this in code:

```
std::cout << APP_VERSION;
```

For more sophisticated VERSION info, kindly be referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317373/6214440).

Comment: In general it is unreliable to refer to answers by order, due to voting and which tab the user may select. Rather use the 'share' item to get a link directly to the answer.

Comment: @SteveFallows: Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Answering duplicate questions just adds to the noise and is discouraged. It's a waste of time, pretty much.